# CK Editor 5 built from source + Vue JS + Using component locally = duplicated

Tags: vue.js, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I have a set of components in my page like this:

`BlogEntryPointComponent` that contains `NewBlogComponent` and `BlogEditComponent`

both `NewBlogComponent` and `BlogEditComponent` use the following code:

```
import BlogEditor from '../../../../js/ckeditor/blogeditor.ts'

export default {
  components:{
    ckeditor: BlogEditor.ckeditor
  },
  data(){
    return{
       editor: BlogEditor.editor,
       editorConfig: BlogEditor.config
    }
  },
  ...
```

so now I mount `BlogEntryPointComponent` but the problem is that this is causing error `ckeditor-duplicated-modules: Some CKEditor 5 modules are duplicated`

The [error page help](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/support/error-codes.html#error-ckeditor-duplicated-modules) talks about using two different builds on one page; I guess I am in this case... but those are are two different independent components; how can this be ?

So I tried building the editor from source as per what the doc recommends and I have the same problem..

the editor is the same imported file in both components.

here is the editor:

```
import EssentialsPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials';
import UploadAdapterPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-adapter-ckfinder/src/uploadadapter';
import AutoformatPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-autoformat/src/autoformat';
import BoldPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/bold';
import ItalicPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/italic';
import BlockQuotePlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-block-quote/src/blockquote';
import HeadingPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-heading/src/heading';
import LinkPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link/src/link';
import ListPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list/src/list';
import ParagraphPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph/src/paragraph';
import AlignmentPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment/src/alignment';
import EmbedPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-media-embed/src/mediaembed';
import MentionPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-mention/src/mention';
import HighlightPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-highlight/src/highlight'

import ClassicEditorBase from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-    classic/src/classiceditor';

import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue/dist/ckeditor.js'

export default {

ckeditor: CKEditor.component,

editor:ClassicEditorBase,

config:{
    plugins: [
        EssentialsPlugin,
        BoldPlugin,
        ItalicPlugin,
        LinkPlugin,
        ParagraphPlugin,
        AlignmentPlugin,
        ListPlugin,
        HeadingPlugin,
        BlockQuotePlugin,
        AutoformatPlugin,
        UploadAdapterPlugin,
        EmbedPlugin,
        MentionPlugin,
        HighlightPlugin
    ],

    toolbar: {
        items: [
            'heading',
            '|',
            'bold',
            'italic',
            'alignment',
            'link',
            'bulletedList',
            'numberedList',
            'mediaEmbed',
            'blockQuote',
            'highlight',
            'undo',
            'redo'
        ]
    }
}

}
```

package.json

```
{
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.5",
"@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.1.0",
"@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-adapter-ckfinder": "^11.0.1",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment": "^11.1.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-autoformat": "^11.0.1",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles": "^11.1.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-block-quote": "^11.0.1",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-utils": "^12.0.1",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-webpack-plugin": "^8.0.1",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-easy-image": "^11.0.1",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic": "^12.1.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials": "^11.0.1",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-heading": "^11.0.1",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image": "^13.0.1",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link": "^11.0.1",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list": "^12.0.1",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph": "^11.0.1",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark": "^13.0.1",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-undo": "^11.0.1",
"@types/jquery": "^3.3.22",
"babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
"clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
"copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.4",
"css-loader": "^2.1.0",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
"file-loader": "^2.0.0",
"html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
"imports-loader": "^0.8.0",
"jquery": "^3.3.1",
"less-loader": "^4.1.0",
"mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.7.0",
"node-sass": "^4.12.0",
"optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.1",
"sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
"select2": "^4.0.6-rc.1",
"style-loader": "^0.23.1",
"terser-webpack-plugin": "^1.3.0",
"to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
"toastr": "^2.1.4",
"ts-loader": "^5.2.2",
"tslint": "^5.11.0",
"typescript": "^3.1.3",
"url-loader": "^1.1.2",
"vue-cool-select": "^1.6.2",
"vue-loader": "^15.6.1",
"vue-select": "2.4.0",
"vue-style-loader": "^4.1.2",
"vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.22",
"webpack": "^4.32.2",
"webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
"webpack-manifest-plugin": "^2.0.4",
"webpack-notifier": "^1.7.0",
"write-file-webpack-plugin": "^4.4.1"
},
"dependencies": {
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^12.1.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document": "^12.1.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-highlight": "^11.0.1",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-media-embed": "^11.1.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-mention": "^10.0.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue": "^1.0.0-beta.2",
"axios": "^0.19.0",
"moment": "^2.24.0",
"postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
"pretty-checkbox-vue": "^1.1.9",
"raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
"svg-url-loader": "^2.3.2",
"vue": "^2.5.22",
"vue-date-pick": "^1.1.0",
"vue-router": "^3.0.2",
"vuelayers": "^0.11.4"
}
```

Comment: You could share you `package.json` entries. It looks like some packages have different versions and are required twice. This happens if one of packages (A) is required by other package (B) in other version then in pakcage.json.

Comment: @jodator I updated the question with the infos

Comment: @jodator I had the same problem before NOT building from source just using the classis editor

Comment: You should remove your node_modules folder, and delete your package.lock or yarn.lock file. Then npm install again. 

Deleting the lock files was key for me.

Comment: @Sam - What helped me get around this issue was removing all the CKEditor packages/modules and adding them one by one through npm. This helped me know which packages were needed as dependencies and which were also needed as devDependencies. Also another thing to note is that the `@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-*` packages have a lot of pre-packaged modules. So i'd start by removing them since you're not referencing them in your code. If that doesn't work, remove all packages then see what packages you need and install them on a as-needed basis.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is I updated all the packages related to ckeditor5 and added `@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui@latest`

When I updated all the packages related to ck5editor I encounred this new multiple errors

```
plugincollection-plugin-name-conflict through duplicate.....
```

https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/1505

so I deleted the `node_modules` and `package.lock or yarn.lock` and `npm install again`

Most probably the cause of the errors is if you have newer version of some plugins and also have older version, it will return an error since it seems you are using both the new and old version or you can't use newer version of plugins with older version of core plugins